# Tuple unpacking in list construction (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2, iterable-unpacking

I'd love to use tuple unpacking on the right hand side in assignments:

```
>>> a = [3,4]

>>> b = [1,2,*a]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
```

OF course, I can do:

```
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> b.extend(a)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But I consider this cumbersome. Am I mising a point? An easy way?
Is it planned to have this? Or is there a reason for explicitly not having it in the language?

Part of the problem is that all container types use a constructor which expect an iterable and do not accept a *args argument. I could subclass, but that's introducing some non-pythonic noise to scripts that others are supposed to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in Python 3.5 as described in [PEP 448](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448):

```
>>> a=[3,4]
>>> b=[1,2,*a]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use add operator:

```
a = [3, 4]
b = [1, 2] + a
```

Comment: It had to be that simple. There weren't any questions on this. Thanks for pointing out the obvious. *sigh*

Answer (score 7):

You have a few options, but the best one is to use list concatenation (`+`):

```
b = [1,2] + a
```

---

If you really want to be able to use the `*` syntax, you can create your own list wrapper:

```
def my_list(*args):
    return list(args)
```

then you can call it as:

```
a = 3,4
b = my_list(1,2,*a)
```

I suppose the benefit here is that `a` doesn't need to be a list, it can be any Sequence type.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not planned. The `*arg` arbitrary parameter list (and `**kw` keyword arguments mapping) only applies to python [call invocations](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#calls) (mirrored by [`*arg` and `**kw` function signatures](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)), and to the left-hand side of an [iterable assignment](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

You can simply concatenate the two lists:

```
b = [10, 2] + a
```